# How to Read/Convert Long RAW in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In an old application (no source code available) long texts with over 40.000 characters are stored in an Oracle database in a table column of type `LONG RAW`. We now want to transfer the texts into another Oracle database and want to display their content. Somehow the old application was capable to do so. However, we always run into a 4000 byte limit...

How can we export/import and display the content in a human readable `VARCHAR2` (or multiple ones).

All convert functions we tried seam not to work. For example `TO_LOB` or `TO_CLOB`.

```
ORA-00932: Inconsistent datentype: - expected, LONG BINARY found
ORA-00932: Inconsistent datentype: CHAR expected, LONG BINARY found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TO_LOB.html):

> TO_LOB converts LONG or LONG RAW values in the column long_column to LOB values. You can apply this function only to a LONG or LONG RAW column, and only in the select list of a subquery in an INSERT statement.

So you can't do:

```
select to_lob(old_column) from old_table;

ORA-00932: Inconsistent datentype: - expected, LONG BINARY found
```

But you can move the data into a BLOB column in another table:

```
insert into new_table(new_column)
select to_lob(old_column) from old_table;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/07TjiqLW)

Once you have the data as a BLOB you can manage it as a binary value, or if it represents text then you can convert it to a CLOB - using the appropriate character set - with the `dbms_lob` package.

Comment: This did the trick. Thx. I used http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convert_blob_to_clob_script.htm  to convert the `blob` into a `clob`.